# Error loading wordpress pages except home page in the host

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a website with wordpress. It works on the local host, and I have uploaded and I have done everything for the DB in host. I have changed the 'siteurl' and 'home' in the DB. It works for the home page, but for other pages I receive the following error:

```
 Not Found

 The requested URL /ØªÙ…Ø§Ø³-Ø¨Ø§-Ù…Ø§/ was not found on this server.
```

Comment: try to flush your permalinks Settings -> permalinks -> save. Also you could check this article - http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Comment: Looking at the request path it might also be that your setup does not handle utf strings correctly.

Comment: Might wanna check the .htaccess file too, when mine has gotten corrupt in the past, the homepage would be the only page to load.